A horror movie with a murderous cook/chef/cannibal
I've been trying to find the name of a horror movie for years.
I feel like it was set in a hospital or asylum or some such and the patients escaped and were maybe taken over by a kind of fungus or something?
The only scene I really remember is when a big black cook/chef woman is killing and eating the other patients (or medical staff?) while another woman tries to talk calmly to her and escape... I'm pretty sure she manages to kill the cook and escape.
I know it's not much information, but I'd be sooo greatful if anyone remembers it!
I would say it was made in the last ten years give or take.

What language was the movie in and about when did you see it? Recognize any actors or how did they look?

The year might help, too. I remember someone asking about this before, but can't find the old question (or remember the answer) at the moment, sorry.

That's the TV movie Medium Raw: Night of the Wolf from 2010. Sandi Ross plays the cannibal cook who teaches how to make a human soufflé.

